# UI of the flutter app is different in the released apk then that from the debug apk (eg: change in theme color of app, button size, etc.)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Changes observed in the UI of the released APK are:
Button size got changed, overall theme color of the app got changed, size of images got reduced...

**Message I am getting while building the released apk:**
`

```
e: C:/Users/yash/AndroidStudioProjects/new_leader_app/build/libphonenumber_plugin/.transforms/3956b74c61ac78f601aec837377fa8a1/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!
/META-INF/libphonenumber_plugin_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/AndroidStudioProjects/new_leader_app/build/package_info_plus/.transforms/7ddc4ccbc2f5f29d002e8c3b83b7e293/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/MET
A-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/AndroidStudioProjects/new_leader_app/build/device_info_plus/.transforms/5158155ecc0275270d02ef58688272ae/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META
-INF/device_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0c3448bdc54b24e2657ed2b98024dd6d/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/M
ETA-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/M
ETA-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/M
ETA-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/yash/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.0/cd65c21cfd1eec4d44ef09f9f52b6d9f8a720636/kotlin-stdlib-commo
n-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

**Solutions I have tried:**

1. Changed the Kotlin version.
2. Upgraded the Flutter dependencies.
3. Removed Obfuscation while building the released apk.
4. Implemented ProGuard in the flutter app.

Comment: Just wondering, are your debug builds made on the same computer as your release builds? If they are made on separate machines one could be running a different flutter version than the other. The thing is flutter 3.16 and higher uses Material 3 by default and lower versions Material 2 and there is a significant change of how your app would look between those versions. It might not be the case for you but that's what first crossed my mind.

Comment: release and debug builds are on the same computer.

Comment: Please provide the first `main()` function which runs the app and the screen used by `runApp(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help us with the above problem.

However, I have found a solution to this problem, which worked for me.

Set 'useMAterial3' in 'MaterialApp' as '**false**'.

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    primarySwatch: const MaterialColor(
      0xFFF87225,
      <int, Color>{
        50: Color(0xFFF87225),
        100: Color(0xFFF87225),
        200: Color(0xFFF87225),
        300: Color(0xFFF87225),
        400: Color(0xFFF87225),
        500: Color(0xFFF87225),
        600: Color(0xFFF87225),
        700: Color(0xFFF87225),
        800: Color(0xFFF87225),
        900: Color(0xFFF87225),
      },
    ),
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
    useMaterial3: false,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using online resources like Fonts, which require the internet. Release builds don't have internet permission by default.

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file located at `<your_project>/android/app/src/main` and add the following line of internet permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
</manifest>
```

If this doesn't work, please make sure that you are using the right Flutter Version, correct flavor configuration and don't have any debug specific code.